# Calculate Discrete Fourier Transform by using c#

Tags: c#, mathematics, transformation

There is a definition of Discrete Fourier Transform:

> [image]

I want to calculate amplitude and phase of a transformed sequence.

> [image]

I tried :

```
 public ArrayList phase = new ArrayList();
 public ArrayList amp = new ArrayList();
 public float phi = 0;

 void Start ()
 {
      DFT();
      foreach (var ampList in amp)
      {
        Debug.Log(ampList);
      }
 }


 void DFT()
 {
  //Given sequence of Numbers

  float[]  X = {1,2,3};
  float[]  Y = {2,3,5};
  float  N = X.Length;
  float re = 0;
  float im = 0;

  for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
  {
      //The discrete Fourier transform, lists of Re & Im instead of a+ib
      for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
       {
           float phi =  (Mathf.PI * k *n)/N;
           re += X[n] * Mathf.Cos(phi) - Y[n] * Mathf.Sin(phi);
           im -= Y[n] * Mathf.Cos(phi) - X[n] * Mathf.Sin(phi);
       }

      re = re/N;
      im = im/N;
      var  ampp = Mathf.Sqrt(re*re + im*im);
      var  phasse  = Mathf.Atan2(re,im);

      phase.Add(phasse);
      amp.Add(ampp);
  }
}
```

but answer is Not correct, I use Wolfram Mathematica to check the answer :

[image]

> [image]

Comment: This looks like a general programming problem that doesn't require game-specific expertise to answer, since discrete Fourier transforms are used in many non-game fields. You may find you get answers faster on [our general programming sister site StackOverflow](https://StackOverflow.com) due to their higher traffic. Or you may find more Fourier experts on the [Digital Signal Processing StackExchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/). Just be sure to delete the copy here if you choose to ask elsewhere — cross-posting is discouraged on the SE network of sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of minor issues that are getting in your way. The following corrections are assuming you are using the definition you provided by Wikipedia:

1. The `re` and `im` variables should be inside the `for` loop for variable `k`, so that they get reset for every element of the output sequence
2. `phi` is missing a factor of `2`
3. The signs of some of the `sin` and `cos` terms are reversed
4. There is no need to divide `re` and `im` by `N`

The final code should look something more like this:

```
float[] X = {1, 2, 3};
float[] Y = {2, 3, 5};
float N = X.Length;

for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
    float re = 0;
    float im = 0;

    //The discrete Fourier transform, lists of Re & Im instead of a+ib
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        float phi = (2 * Mathf.PI * k * n) / N;
        re += X[n] * Mathf.Cos(phi) + Y[n] * Mathf.Sin(phi);
        im += Y[n] * Mathf.Cos(phi) - X[n] * Mathf.Sin(phi);
    }

    var ampp = Mathf.Sqrt(re * re + im * im);
    var phasse = Mathf.Atan2(re, im);

    phase.Add(phasse);
    amp.Add(ampp);
}
```

Also, Wolfram Mathematica's `Fourier` function uses a different convention by default than the one you are using. See the section on `FourierParameters` in [the documentation of the `Fourier` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html). It looks like the definition found in Wikipedia is using the "signal processing" convention, and so you would need to try this in Wolfram Mathematica instead.

```
Fourier[{1 + 2 * I, 2 + 3 * I, 3 + 5 * I}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

Unfortunately I do not currently have access to Wolfram Mathematica for testing, and Wolfram Alpha does not seem to support this syntax according to [this stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089502/wolfram-alpha-fourierparameters-not-working-with-discrete-fourier-transform), so I will leave that part up to you :-)

As a final note, while it is definitely good to implement the Discrete Fourier Transform yourself as a learning exercise, I would recommend searching for a library which implements this for use in an actual application. Especially if you are going to be processing a lot of data, then a "[Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)" implementation in a good library is likely to be faster, better tested, and more accurate than anything you could make yourself in a reasonable amount of time.

Hope this helps, and best of luck!